# IsLetter validation with autocomplete

Tags: kotlin

I'm encountering an issue with validating a string, I want to check if the string contains only letters, I have this function:

```
private fun String.onlyLetters(): Boolean = all { it.isLetter() }
```

It mostly works fine, but when I choose the string from the autocomplete suggestions, the function returns false.

Steps to reproduce:

1- add this code:

```
OutlinedTextField(
                        value = text,
                        onValueChange = {
                            if (it.all { it.isLetter() }){
                                text = it
                            }
                    },
                )
```

2- Type something in the textfield, then choose a text from the autocomplete suggestions.

When you do that, the text won't be added to the textfield. Any idea why is this the case?

Comment: do the autocomplete suggestions include non-letter characters, such as spaces, punctuation, or special characters?

Comment: the suggestions is only a word, a string, for example you type "hel" you will see "hello" as a suggestion

Comment: So, what *is* the content of the autocompleted string?

Comment: Where is `text` defined, and what is its scope?  What would be the effect of changing it?

Comment: @gidds I'm putting all the code in one place in the main function to reproduce the problem, text has no effects, it's only used in the text field above

Comment: So if setting `text` has no effect once the text field has been created, what do you expect your `onValueChange` listener to do?

Comment: @gidds not sure what you mean, did you try to reproduce the problem with the code above?